# How do I restart the scrapyd daemon?

Tags: python, daemon, scrapy

I've installed the scrapyd daemon on an EC2 server exactly as described in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/scrapyd.html).  Now I've changed some of the configuration variables in `/etc/scrapyd/conf.d/000-default`.

How do I get scrapyd to recognize those changes?  I assume it involves restarting the daemon, but I can't find any good guidance on how to do so.

One complicating factor: I have a bunch of crawls queued up, and I'd rather not lose them.  I think scrapy knows how to quit and resume them gracefully, but this feature isn't well-documented.  Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple.

Kill the process like this:

```
kill -INT $(cat /var/run/scrapyd.pid)
```

Then restart it like this:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/twistd -ny /usr/share/scrapyd/scrapyd.tac -u scrapy -g nogroup --pidfile /var/run/scrapyd.pid -l /var/log/scrapyd/scrapyd.log &
```

As far as I can tell, both commands need to be run as root.

Comment: BTW, this will not immediately terminate runners spawned by scrapyd.  Those processes need to be terminated separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed scrapyd via apt on an Ubuntu or Debian machine, the following should work:

```
sudo service scrapyd reload
```

Whether it will persist your scheduled spider runs I do not know know, however.

Comment: This didn't  work for me.  I get "reload: Unknown instance:   "

Comment: Mhh, I get this error message only when I try reloading but the daemon isn't running.

Comment: This wiill unfortunatlly kill the running spiders which is everything else then idle if you have them running for tens of hours. Not recommended.

Comment: @merlin, did you find a better solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/scrapyd restart
```