# Restart or Kill Scrapyd server

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have scrapyd installed and running on my Mac but I want to restart or kill it - I think it might be a reason that I can't get scrapyd-client to function after installing through pip.

I can't find a way to kill or restart it. I installed through pip and ran the following command to start it:

```
scrapyd
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428143/how-do-i-restart-the-scrapyd-daemon

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
killall scrapyd
```

This will kill Scrapyd hence all the running jobs are also killed.