# Scrapy: run a spider from python script and wait it until the end of its execution

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I created a small `Scrapy` project with this structure:

```html
scrapyProject/
 ├── scrapy.cfg
 └── scrapyProject
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── crawl_products.py
        └── __init__.py
```

The `crawl_products.py` contain the spider `products_spider`. To start the spider I am using:

```sh
scrapy crawl products_spider
```

Now I want **to start the spider from another python script and wait until its execution end.**

**IF IT CAN HELP** : The other script from which I want to run the spider is a `django` view

Answer (score 2):

You can find half of the solution in this very good explanation in the **[scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)**

**BUT, and that's the more important half of the solution, never ever run a scraper directly from a django view (neither from some other web framework).**

Please, I have seen this way too often, and doing so will block your web app. As a result your view will run into a browser timeout and at some point your app won't be able to process other requests.

**The clean solution** here is to use a background process that runs the scraper. A good library for this is `celery` and this topic has been discussed in detail here already: [Running Scrapy spiders in a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528739/running-scrapy-spiders-in-a-celery-task)

Comment: Celery is overkill for Django. Use django-q

Comment: Django-q might be more light-weight, but in this case celery has the big advantage of running completely outside of django. Integrating scrapy scrapers into something that's controlled by django can be a huge pain - at least it was on every occasion when I tried in the past ...