# docker scrapy spyder not auto restart

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, celery

I am running docker+python+spyder

My spyder run just as much as my concurency limit, idk, can someone help me to understand it ?

my docker-compose.py

```
celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./celery-queue/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A tasksSpider worker --loglevel=info  --concurrency=5 -n myuser@%n
    env_file:
    - .env
    depends_on:
    - redis
```

My spider code :

```
def spider_results_group():
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(groupSpider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    process.stop()
    return results
```

With this code, i could run spider multiple times, but only 5 times, when i check it, i think this is because my concurency is only 5, and when this run again(6th), it stuck..

if need other code, please ask

Answer (score 0):

solved by using this command :

```
    command: -A tasksSpider worker --loglevel=info  --concurrency=5 --max-tasks-per-child=1 -n myuser@%n
```

got answer from :
[Running Scrapy spiders in a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528739/running-scrapy-spiders-in-a-celery-task)

Comment: note this "maybe" different issue because if iam trying outside docker, my code perfectly run, but when it run in docker+celery it got only maximum limit of celery concurency..

Comment: i mean about duplicate thing.. XD